# discord.py finding members from another guild

Tags: discord.py

I know there is a method to get a member's id for example from the **same guild**, but can you do this if the member is **not** in the same server with the bot?

Comment: Can you provide a more specific example of your intention? Generally, bots can't access anything related to servers they are not a member of, including `Member`s.

Comment: You can not access users who don't have any mutual guilds with your bot.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers, I actually found out what I was doing wrong. I should have put `commands.UserConverter` instead of `commands.MemberConverter` in the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, yes you can, even when the bot isn't mutually on the server that the user is in.

I made a function for it.

```py
import requests
import os

def find_user(id_of_user):
    payload = {}
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bot " + os.getenv("BOT_TOKEN")}
    response = requests.request(
        "GET",
        f"https://discord.com/api/v9/users/{id_of_user}",
        headers=headers,
        data=payload,
    )
    return response.json()
```

You may replace `os.getenv("BOT_TOKEN")` with your bot token either in the `env` file or just directly paste it in the source code replacing the `os.getenv(...)`

Example use of this :

```py
import requests
import os


def find_user(id_of_user):
    payload = {}
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bot " + os.getenv("BOT_TOKEN")}
    response = requests.request(
        "GET",
        f"https://discord.com/api/v9/users/{id_of_user}",
        headers=headers,
        data=payload,
    )
    return response.json()


info = find_user(235148962103951360)
for x in info.keys():
    print(f"{x} : {info[x]}")
```

Output :

```
id : 235148962103951360
username : Carl-bot
avatar : cececd50fdc87b29929e65c768f24ad6
discriminator : 1536
public_flags : 65536
bot : True
banner : None
banner_color : None
accent_color : None
```

(The bot was in 0 guilds when this code was executed)

Note : Remember that using `requests` is blocking if you are going to use this alongside asynchronous code, use `aiohttp` if you are going to use this function along with dpy.

[docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-user)